# Jquery resizable plugin, resizing object by dragging edges of that object

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-resizable

I like the resizable plugin by JQuery ui: http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/

I want to implement it in my script, but to do that I need the plugin to re-size the element by me dragging any of the four corners of it not just the top and left one as I can see in the demo. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reading the doc(which you liked to) helps:

$( ".selector" ).resizable({ handles: "all" });

Comment: I looked. Couldn't find it. Thanks :)